# How to replace some character in long text with best performance in java?

Tags: java, performance, text, replace

I want to replace a special character with some codes in java. The text is too huge and i have to care about performance.
What would be the best possibilities?

More Info:
the input would be HTML file, which contains a larg amount of text and I should replace forexample all 'z' (which has a small probabilty of occurance in a text) with a (which has a high probabilty of occurance in a text)

Comment: Check out using [regular expressions](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html).

Comment: This question is too vague. How is the text stored? In memory, in a file? What are you replacing? What kind of performance are you expecting? We can't answer this question like this. Please update your answer with more details using the `edit` button underneath your question to provide more information.

Comment: Thanks Brian. I added "More Info"

Answer (score 0):

You should use `BufferedReader` to read the "huge" text and you can read line by line of your text file without the performance headache. Also see [this](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-file-from-java-bufferedreader-example).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot replace text in a string as strings are immutable. So you must create a copy of the string. I would do something like this:

```
public final class Codec {

  public static void encode(InputStream in, OutputStream out, char special, char quote) {
    char current;
    while ( ( current = in.read() ) != -1 ) {
      if ( current == special || current == quote ) { out.write(quote); }
      out.write(current);
    }
  }
}
```

If the text is really huge and does not fit into memory the streams are just right.

If it's only strings use String.replace(...)